# Import wizard with subqueries

Tags: sql, excel, import

I want to import 100k+ rows on to a SQL Server table.

I have my insert like this (observe the 6th value that is a subquery):

```
INSERT INTO BD_S3I.dbo.AGENDA 
(COD_UNDFBR, COD_DCPLNA, COD_TECNCA, COD_ATVIDE, DAT_PROGM_AGENDA, NUM_SQNCL_AGENDA, DAT_FINAL_AGENDA, COD_OCORR, COD_ROTA, NUM_SEMAN_PRGINS, NUM_DIAIN_PRGINS, DAT_INIC_PRGINS, MRC_SITUA_AGENDA, DAT_SUSPN_AGENDA, DAT_CONCL_AGENDA, DAT_REPRG_AGENDA, DCR_SITUA_AGENDA, DCR_AGENDA, MRC_AVISO_AGENDA, MRC_NEGLG_AGENDA, NUM_PERIO_PRGINS, DAT_DIAIN_PRGINS, DAT_JUSTN_AGENDA, COD_MTVNVS, MRC_ERP_AGENDA, COD_USUS3I_JUSTN)

VALUES

(1, 290, 2, 6, '2017-09-11 00:00:00.000', (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(AGENDA.NUM_SQNCL_AGENDA) + 1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE MAX(AGENDA.NUM_SQNCL_AGENDA) + 1 END FROM AGENDA WHERE AGENDA.COD_UNDFBR = 1 AND AGENDA.COD_DCPLNA = 290 AND AGENDA.COD_TECNCA = 2 AND AGENDA.COD_ATVIDE = 6 AND AGENDA.DAT_PROGM_AGENDA = '2017-09-11 00:00:00.000'), '2017-09-17 00:00:00.000', NULL, 492, NULL, NULL, '2017-07-24 08:30:00.000', 'P', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'S', 'S', 7, '2017-07-24 00:00:00.000', NULL, NULL, 'N', NULL);
```

I put al the 100k inserts below each other and start the import. It is working fine, but thakes too much time to execute all the 100k+ rows.

I was thinking to use the import wizard (the time is better?).

The problem is that when I choose the excel file with my data, the import wizard do not understand the subquery on the value. It calls it a longtext.

[image: Image with subquery]

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can not run a subquery in your values list.

Answer (score 0):

Select atleast one return type that's needs to be inserted into 6th column. 
Just like

```
( SELECT x = CASE .... )
```

Or use return type along with subquery at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert your `INSERT...VALUES` to `INSERT...SELECT` which works since all other values are scalars and can be included inline with the subquery's `SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO BD_S3I.dbo.AGENDA (COD_UNDFBR, COD_DCPLNA, COD_TECNCA, COD_ATVIDE, 
                               DAT_PROGM_AGENDA, NUM_SQNCL_AGENDA, DAT_FINAL_AGENDA, 
                               COD_OCORR, COD_ROTA, NUM_SEMAN_PRGINS, NUM_DIAIN_PRGINS, 
                               DAT_INIC_PRGINS, MRC_SITUA_AGENDA, DAT_SUSPN_AGENDA, 
                               DAT_CONCL_AGENDA, DAT_REPRG_AGENDA, DCR_SITUA_AGENDA, 
                               DCR_AGENDA, MRC_AVISO_AGENDA, MRC_NEGLG_AGENDA, 
                               NUM_PERIO_PRGINS, DAT_DIAIN_PRGINS, DAT_JUSTN_AGENDA, 
                               COD_MTVNVS, MRC_ERP_AGENDA, COD_USUS3I_JUSTN)

SELECT 1, 290, 2, 6, '2017-09-11 00:00:00.000', 
       CASE WHEN MAX(AGENDA.NUM_SQNCL_AGENDA) + 1 IS NULL 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE MAX(AGENDA.NUM_SQNCL_AGENDA) + 1 
       END,
       '2017-09-17 00:00:00.000', NULL, 492, NULL, 
        NULL, '2017-07-24 08:30:00.000', 'P', 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'S', 'S', 7, 
        '2017-07-24 00:00:00.000', NULL, NULL, 'N', NULL

FROM AGENDA 
WHERE AGENDA.COD_UNDFBR = 1 AND AGENDA.COD_DCPLNA = 290 
  AND AGENDA.COD_TECNCA = 2 AND AGENDA.COD_ATVIDE = 6 
  AND AGENDA.DAT_PROGM_AGENDA = '2017-09-11 00:00:00.000')
```